# Bash Array Accessing with File Globs

Tags: arrays, bash

I am very new to bash scripting but am having trouble accessing an array.  (or what I believe to be an array)  I am using a file glob to get the contents of an array.

I simply want to print each file and then allow the user to pick one based on its index.  However I am noticing that everything is stored in the first element of the array.  What am I missing?  Is file globbing not the best idea here for what I want?

```
files=templates/*.tex
fnum=0
for file in $files
do
        echo $fnum : $file
        # bash expression is ((expression)) $(( expression )) expects a command
        (( fnum++ ))
done
read -p "Which file would you like to include: " answer
if [ $answer -ge 0 ] && [ $answer -lt $fnum ]
then
        echo ${$files[0]}
else
        echo bad range...
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Aside: There are a lot of bugs in here that http://shellcheck.net/ would find automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`files` is not an array; `files=( templates/*.tex )` is.

```
files=( templates/*.tex )
fnum=0
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
        echo "$fnum : $file"
        (( fnum++ ))
done
read -p "Which file would you like to include: " answer
if [ "$answer" -ge 0 ] && [ "$answer" -lt "$fnum" ]
then
        echo "${files[answer]}"
else
        echo bad range...
        exit 1
fi
```

More idiomatically in `bash` (not identical, but provides the same basic functionality much more concisely):

```
PS3="Which file would you like to include: "
select answer in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$answer"
    break
done
```

Comment: As an aside, you can get rid of `fnum`, the `read` command, and the range check using the `select` command in `bash`.

Comment: "${files[@]} what does this mean?

Comment: also for the ${$files\[answer]} line it is saying its a bad substitution.  $answer gets the same result

Comment: @9er, `${files[$answer]}` is the correct way to write that.

Comment: @chepner, ...btw, you have rather a lot of quoting bugs here. Mind if I step in and fix them up?

Comment: The `${$...}` is a bug I introduced; the rest I didn't bother fixing, but I will.

Comment: `"${files[@]}"` expands to a sequence of words, one per element from the array. The quotes ensure that any array elements that contain whitespace will remain a single word in the resulting sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Your files variable is a string, try `files=( templates/*.tex )` if I am not mistaking this should make an array of the files

To iterate over the array you should use `for file in "${files[@]}"`